# vim colorscheme not working, from file or colorscheme command

Tags: unix, vim

I'm trying to use [a color scheme](https://github.com/drewtempelmeyer/palenight.vim) for vim, but I can't get it to load. I've placed `~/.vim/colors/palenight.vim` with the following:

```
let s:overrides = get(g:, "palenight_color_overrides", {})

let s:colors = {
      \ "red": get(s:overrides, "red", { "gui": "#ff5370", "cterm": "204", "cterm16": "1" }),
      \ "light_red": get(s:overrides, "light_red", { "gui": "#ff869a", "cterm": "204", "cterm16": "1" }),
      \ "dark_red": get(s:overrides, "dark_red", { "gui": "#BE5046", "cterm": "196", "cterm16": "9" }),
      \ "green": get(s:overrides, "green", { "gui": "#C3E88D", "cterm": "114", "cterm16": "2" }),
      \ "yellow": get(s:overrides, "yellow", { "gui": "#ffcb6b", "cterm": "180", "cterm16": "3" }),
      \ "dark_yellow": get(s:overrides, "dark_yellow", { "gui": "#F78C6C", "cterm": "173", "cterm16": "11" }),
      \ "blue": get(s:overrides, "blue", { "gui": "#82b1ff", "cterm": "39", "cterm16": "4" }),
      \ "purple": get(s:overrides, "purple", { "gui": "#c792ea", "cterm": "170", "cterm16": "5" }),
      \ "cyan": get(s:overrides, "cyan", { "gui": "#89DDFF", "cterm": "38", "cterm16": "6" }),
      \ "white": get(s:overrides, "white", { "gui": "#bfc7d5", "cterm": "145", "cterm16": "7" }),
      \ "black": get(s:overrides, "black", { "gui": "#292D3E", "cterm": "235", "cterm16": "0" }),
      \ "visual_black": get(s:overrides, "visual_black", { "gui": "NONE", "cterm": "NONE", "cterm16": "0" }),
      \ "comment_grey": get(s:overrides, "comment_grey", { "gui": "#697098", "cterm": "59", "cterm16": "15" }),
      \ "gutter_fg_grey": get(s:overrides, "gutter_fg_grey", { "gui": "#4B5263", "cterm": "238", "cterm16": "15" }),
      \ "cursor_grey": get(s:overrides, "cursor_grey", { "gui": "#2C323C", "cterm": "236", "cterm16": "8" }),
      \ "visual_grey": get(s:overrides, "visual_grey", { "gui": "#3E4452", "cterm": "237", "cterm16": "15" }),
      \ "menu_grey": get(s:overrides, "menu_grey", { "gui": "#3E4452", "cterm": "237", "cterm16": "8" }),
      \ "special_grey": get(s:overrides, "special_grey", { "gui": "#3B4048", "cterm": "238", "cterm16": "15" }),
      \ "vertsplit": get(s:overrides, "vertsplit", { "gui": "#181A1F", "cterm": "59", "cterm16": "15" }),
      \}

function! palenight#GetColors()
  return s:colors
endfunction
```

This doesn't load though when I `vi some-file` -- if I do `:colorscheme palenight`, it likewise doesn't work. If I do `:scriptnames` it shows `palenight.vim` in the list. What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

The [text you quoted](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drewtempelmeyer/palenight.vim/master/autoload/palenight.vim) should be placed in `~/.vim/autoload/palenight.vim`

Place [the color file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drewtempelmeyer/palenight.vim/master/colors/palenight.vim) in `~/.vim/colors/palenight.vim`

In your `.vimrc`, add the following lines:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme palenight
```